# Efficient way to convert string to string representation of the binary

Tags: string, performance, go, binary, type-conversion

I'm searching how to convert a string to a string representation in binary with best performance.

So I started with something similar to the following:

```
func binConvertOrig(s string) string {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        fmt.Fprintf(&buf, "%08b", s[i])
    }
    return buf.String()
}

s := "Test"
log.Printf("%s => binConvertOrig => %s", s, binConvertOrig(s))
```

But it seems that `fmt.Fprintf` & `bytes.Buffer` are not very efficient.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing beats a pre-calculated lookup table, especially if it's stored in a slice or array (and not in a map), and the converter allocates a byte slice for the result with just the right size:

```
var byteBinaries [256][]byte

func init() {
    for i := range byteBinaries {
        byteBinaries[i] = []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%08b", i))
    }
}

func strToBin(s string) string {
    res := make([]byte, len(s)*8)
    for i := len(s) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        copy(res[i*8:], byteBinaries[s[i]])
    }
    return string(res)
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(strToBin("\x01\xff"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BwqBH2F7nz)):

```
0000000111111111
```

#### Benchmarks

Let's see how fast it can get:

```
var texts = []string{
    "\x00",
    "123",
    "1234567890",
    "asdf;lkjasdf;lkjasdf;lkj108fhq098wf34",
}

func BenchmarkOrig(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        for _, t := range texts {
            binConvertOrig(t)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkLookup(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        for _, t := range texts {
            strToBin(t)
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
BenchmarkOrig-4      200000     8526 ns/op       2040 B/op     12 allocs/op
BenchmarkLookup-4   2000000      781 ns/op        880 B/op      8 allocs/op
```

The lookup version (`strToBin()`) is **11 times faster** and uses less memory and allocations. Basically it only uses allocation for the result (which is unavoidable).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is very instructive.

Comment: Great answer. Probably a `range` over `s` can give a small boost though I'm not sure. Also you can try to define a `j` variable for index in the target slice and do `j += copy(res[j:], byteBinaries[s[i]])`. Wonder if it would be a bit efficient?

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok A range over a `string` ranges over the `rune`s, not its `byte`s! And introducing another variable which you would write would most likely perform less. This version does not need to write the index, as it depends on `i`, and `i*8` will be optimized to a bit shift operation by the compiler (e.g.`i<<3`).

Comment: @icza, good point :). Anyway I wonder if direction of iteration makes any difference. Maybe the case on big strings

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok Yeah, I'm not sure either. `len(s)` is not a constant as `s` is not a constant, so it may or may not be cached. I used downward direction just in case it doesn't.

Comment: Doesn't a reverse direction prevent the cache-line optimization that could otherwise occur if you did it forward?

Comment: @Kaedys I don't know.